# Invalid error messages in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am running into a problem when trying to duplicate a project in STS.
I am getting lots of error-messages of type

"Import XY cannot be resolved..."

in my code which runs and builds completely fine with maven and which is a more or less exact copy of the original project (with different artifact ID a.s.o. in the corresponding pom) which is shown as error-free.

What I did until now:

I wasn't sure how STS-duplicate works and thought that some configuration may have been duplicated but would have needed some changes, so I created a new project and inserted the code manually in manually new created classes and added the needed dependencies to the pom.

Again this compiles and runs perfectly while still showing the import errors.

Did anyone run into similar problems and has a solution to this?

(I had something similarly strange in the past where STS showed an error on project-level but no file in the project would have an error-indicator.)

Comment: what happens if you execute "Maven -> Update Project..." ?!? Does that help?

Comment: Can't believe it but that seems to have solved it! If you post that as answer I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: sure, and glad to hear it helps... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a `Maven -> Update Project...`, that should help... :-)